Coverage's dynamic context usage returns 'no contexts were measured'
I'm interested in seeing what test triggers what code via the coverage tool.
I followed the instruction https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contexts.html#dynamic-contexts, to enable dynamic context collection for the coverage run.
I configured the pyproject.toml since my project is managed by Poetry.
I tried it out on a test file via command like:
coverage run --source=/usr/local/google/home/Workspace/p,/usr/local/google/home/.virtualenvs/p/lib64/python3.11/site-packages /usr/local/google/home/Workspace/p/src..._parser_test.py

where, all test methods in the parser test are named following the standard 'test_...'.
The coverage run command seems to finish without complaint (very fast too).
and then I try to generate a report via command:
coverage html --ignore-errors --show-contexts
which shows message
CoverageWarning: No contexts were measured
And on the generated html report, I don't see any annotation/tagging that looks like test methods.
@nedbat, Really appreciate the help. What am I missing here?

Got the coverage tool to read from the configuration in the .toml.

coverage need to run from the same directory as .toml for it to find the config file. It wasn't obvious until I used coverage debug trace which shows the paths the tool's looking for configuration.
Then the configuration for dynamic context, show contexts work as expected.

